# Using Google BigQuery and it's pulling Compute Engine?

Tags: java, google-bigquery

I am trying to run the Java example provided in the following site, using the same pom.xml file and code.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/create-simple-app-api

I took out the parent element from the pom.xml because I thought it was not necessary.

I have posted the pom.xml below:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>query</groupId>
  <artifactId>sample</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>


  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>googleapis</id>
      <url>https://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/mavenrepo</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-bigquery</artifactId>
        <version>v2-rev265-1.21.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-oauth-client</artifactId>
        <version>${project.oauth.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson2</artifactId>
        <version>${project.http.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
      <version>${project.oauth.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
      <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
      <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.8.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.truth</groupId>
      <artifactId>truth</artifactId>
      <version>0.28</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <properties>
    <project.http.version>1.21.0</project.http.version>
    <project.oauth.version>1.21.0</project.oauth.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <build>
      <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
      <resources>
        <resource>
          <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
      </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>5</source>
          <target>5</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

I get the following error in my Console when running in Eclipse:

```
May 07, 2016 10:22:54 PM com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Utils runningOnComputeEngine
WARNING: Failed to detect whether we are running on Google Compute Engine.
java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:93)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:981)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Utils.runningOnComputeEngine(OAuth2Utils.java:86)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialProvider.detectEnvironment(DefaultCredentialProvider.java:183)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialProvider.getDefaultCredentialUnsynchronized(DefaultCredentialProvider.java:110)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialProvider.getDefaultCredential(DefaultCredentialProvider.java:91)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredential.java:213)
    at sample.querysample.createAuthorizedClient(querysample.java:33)
    at sample.querysample.main(querysample.java:113)

May 07, 2016 10:22:54 PM com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Utils runningOnComputeEngine
WARNING: Failed to detect whether we are running on Google Compute Engine.
java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:93)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:981)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Utils.runningOnComputeEngine(OAuth2Utils.java:86)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialProvider.detectEnvironment(DefaultCredentialProvider.java:183)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialProvider.getDefaultCredentialUnsynchronized(DefaultCredentialProvider.java:110)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialProvider.getDefaultCredential(DefaultCredentialProvider.java:91)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredential.java:213)
    at sample.querysample.createAuthorizedClient(querysample.java:33)
    at sample.querysample.main(querysample.java:113)

May 07, 2016 10:22:54 PM com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Utils runningOnComputeEngine
WARNING: Failed to detect whether we are running on Google Compute Engine.
java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:93)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:981)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Utils.runningOnComputeEngine(OAuth2Utils.java:86)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialProvider.detectEnvironment(DefaultCredentialProvider.java:183)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialProvider.getDefaultCredentialUnsynchronized(DefaultCredentialProvider.java:110)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialProvider.getDefaultCredential(DefaultCredentialProvider.java:91)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredential.java:213)
    at sample.querysample.createAuthorizedClient(querysample.java:33)
    at sample.querysample.main(querysample.java:113)

Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running on Google App Engine, Google Compute Engine, or Google Cloud Shell. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialProvider.getDefaultCredential(DefaultCredentialProvider.java:98)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredential.java:213)
    at sample.querysample.createAuthorizedClient(querysample.java:33)
    at sample.querysample.main(querysample.java:113)
```

I don't plan on using Compute Engine, just Google BigQuery.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you read this part of the exception: Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running on Google App Engine, Google Compute Engine, or Google Cloud Shell. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See [https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials) for more information.

Comment: Yep, just create a service account key in the console, save it locally, and point that environment variable at the .json file. Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 6):

Think it is no longer relevant, but in my case problem has been solved by restarting an IDE. I am using Windows and Idea as an IDE. Problem was that I ran IDE before adding GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to system variables. It's like when you add system variable while your command line is running, you should restart your command line to system variable takes effect